# How to change <p> tag class woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, checkout

i am working with woocommerce checkout form but facing a problem.please anyone help me out.i got form-row form-row-first class but i need form-row form-row-wide class within this tag.how to replace it. How to change class p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" to p class="form-row form-row-wide"

Comment: Add question with proper description.

Comment: i got a <p form-row form-row-first> but i need form-row form-row-wide calss within this tag.how to replace it.

How to change class <p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required"> to <p class="form-row form-row-wide">

Comment: You need to read the guideline doc how woocommerce templates can be overwrite within theme , this will help you

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestions @dipmala

Answer (score 1):

Solved, need to include this function into functions.php file. thanks you so much to all.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'amit_checkout_fields_styling', 9999 );

function amit_checkout_fields_styling( $fields ) {

```
$fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['class'][0] = 'form-row-wide';

return $fields;
```

}